# How to split on two string delimters

Tags: ruby

How would I split a string based on two string delimiters like `" of "` and `" in "`.

For example, the string:

```
"dogs in Toronto of Canada"
```

would transform into the array:

```
["dogs", "Toronto", "Canada"]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; here you find something on [ask]. It would be a good starting point to post what you tried so far, showing us that you did some research and attempts before posting.

Comment: Besides "[ask]", please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String#split` with regex:

```
"dogs in Toronto of Canada".split(/\sof\s|\sin\s/)
=> ["dogs", "Toronto", "Canada"]
```

Comment: Also: `/\b(of|in)\b/`

Comment: @tadman, I've just transformed into regex original delimiters with spaces (" or ", " in ").

Comment: `"of dogs in Toronto".split(/\sof\s|\sin\s/) #=> ["of dogs", "Toronto"]` vs `"of dogs in Toronto".split(/\b(?:of|in)\b/) #=> ["", " dogs ", " Toronto"]`.

Comment: @tadman, as you know well, you need a non-capture group: `/\b(?:of|in)\b/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I put in the non-capturing part by habit, then removed it thinking it'd be more concise and require less explanation. It is necessary, you're right.

Comment: Speaking of Toronto, "Go Raptors!".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general-purpose one:

```
dogs.split(/\b\s*(?:of|in)\s*\b/)
```

There's a lot of cruft in there, but it handles irregular spacing, `of` appearing at the start or end of the phrase, and so on.

You can also try this which is even more adaptable at the expense of legibility:

```
splits = %w[ of in at on ]
pattern = Regexp.new('\b\s*%s\s*\b' % Regexp.union(splits))

dogs.split(pattern).reject(&:empty?)
```